# How to fix "The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout" on Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: php, http, timeout, 500-error, iis-8

How to fix "The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout" on Windows 8 Pro?

Installed FileMaker 12 Advanced Server on Windows 8 Pro box

A long running script generates:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Web Publishing\publishing-engine\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 8):

Open Server Manager

At Server Level (not default Web site)

- Double click FastCGI Settings
- open PHP.EXE listed there
- Monitor changes to file php.ini
- activity timeout default is 60s - change to 600s or whatever